# Java, Understanding

Tags: java, string, args

I have the following questions, about this Java Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int A = 12, B = 24;
    int x = A, y = B;
    while (x > 0) {
        y = y + 1;
        x = x - 1;
    }
    System.out.println("the solution is " + y);
}
```

1. What is beeing computed here?
   My solution is, that it's (12-1)+(24+1) = 36. Please correct me if it's the wrong though.
2. For which A and  B there will be an error?
   Honestly, i though about A = 1 and smaller, but it didn't work....can someone help me out?
3. If there's an error, what is the readout?
   I could not answer this, as trying out to get an error (for example setting A = -24) i just did not get an error but another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's check this bit of your code:

```
while (x > 0) {
        y = y + 1;
        x = x - 1;
    }
    System.out.println("the solution is " + y);
```

This is a *loop*. A *while loop*, to be precise.

A loop will continue to iterate until the condition of the loop is *false*

In this case, you have x = 12 and y = 24. Since x value is positive, so it will enter the loop, and continue the calculation for each iterations.

Here are the results you'll get for each iteration:

- x = 11, y = 25
- x = 10, y = 26
- x = 9, y = 27
- x = 8, y = 28
- x = 7, y = 29
- x = 6, y = 30
- x = 5, y = 31
- x = 4, y = 32
- x = 3, y = 33
- x = 2, y = 34
- x = 1, y = 35
- x = 0, y = 36

When you get `x = 0` and `y = 36`, the loop stops, because `x = 0` and it violates the condition. So you get out of the loop. The last value of `y` is 36. That's what you're getting in you `println()`; it's not `x + y`, it's `y` alright.

But when `x = -12`, or `x=-24` or any other negative number, the while condition is false. Your `println()` is outside the loop, so it will display the value of y which is outside the loop, i.e. 24.

You won't get an error for condition of while being false. Even if you `println()` `x` or `y` inside the loop, you won't get any result, but won't get any error either.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I know (already) that it is wrong, it was discussed in another answer here. But if A = 12 and B = 24, the Solution is 36 because it is: A*1+B (?) well, that's what I get compiling it. If x>0 is false, then the solution is always only Y ( B=24). If it is true, the compiler gives me other results, which are always A+B in that case ?

Comment: Please check my edited answer. Hopefully it will remove all confusion. I was previously wrong. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Incrementing `y`, `x` times
2. There'll be no errors for any `A` and `B`. In the "worst" case, the loop won't be executed and the initial value of `y` will be printed
3. Irrelevant

I don't understand your title, there's nothing to do with `String[] args` here.

I'm unsure what's the purpose of this code, even for learning purposes..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65450/discussion-on-answer-by-maroun-maroun-java-understanding).

Answer (score 0):

1. sum of A and B
2. when A<0 the sum is not calculated correctly
3. readout is B when there is error

Comment: *There may be errors if you assign non numeric values* careful with the *error* term. You should explain the difference between a *compiler error* which means that the code won't even compile, thus no way to execute it; and a `RuntimeException` which **is not an error** but means the code compiles fine and there's a problem in the code when its executed (again, a problem, not an error).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, Thanks. But I think the answer is something different and I edited it..